# How can I filter out certain items in an array using php?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to filter out a php array based on some search criteria, but it's not quite working.

I've been trying this code I found on google, but it giving an error?

```
$shortWords = '/'.$_GET['sSearch'].'/i';
$rResult = array_filter($rResult, 
     function($x) use ($shortWords) {
       return preg_match($shortWords,$x);
      });
```

Here is the error:

```
 preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
```

I don't quite know what the "function($x) use...." is doing...my limitations to php.

Here is what the array looks like before the "array_filter()":

```
 array(
    [0] =>
        array(
            ['unit_nbr'] =>'BBC 2'
            ['p_unit_group_id'] =>NULL
            ['name'] =>1
            ['unit_id'] =>22640
            ['properties_id'] =>1450
            )

    [1] =>
        array(

            ['unit_nbr'] =>'BBC 3'
            ['p_unit_group_id'] =>NULL
            ['name'] =>1
            ['unit_id'] =>22641
            ['properties_id'] =>1450
)
```

I would like to have the unit_nbr "BBC 2" remain in the array when I pass that search string over to the function.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks pretty obvious from the error you say you're getting. preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, you're passing it an array. So I have to ask: do you understand what this code does, even if you didn't write it?

Comment: I don't know what $x is and how it is populated...that's probably why I don't understand this...is $rResult being put into $x?

Comment: Then you really need to sit down and read http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php first - it explains what the arguments do, and shows you examples of its use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the multi-dimensional array. When you pass along to the callback, `$x` is the array:

```
    array(
        ['unit_nbr'] =>'BBC 2'
        ['p_unit_group_id'] =>NULL
        ['name'] =>1
        ['unit_id'] =>22640
        ['properties_id'] =>1450
        )
```

but you still need to check the items within that array as well.

```
$shortWords = '/'.$_GET['sSearch'].'/i';
$rResult = array_filter($rResult, 
    function($x) use ($shortWords) {
        foreach ($x as $_x) {
            if (preg_match($shortWords,$_x)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
foreach ($rResult as $okey => $oval) {
    foreach ($oval as $ikey => $ival) {
        if ($ival != $_GET['sSearch']) {
             unset($rResult[$okey]);
        }
    }
}
```

If that's not what your looking for, then I need more information about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: the `use` keyword is for anonymous functions, to indicate that a variable should be treated as in-scope. It's like calling `global $shortWords` without calling `global`.